# IntelliJ IDEA — Please consider switching to the bundled Java runtime that is better suited for IDE

Tags: arch-linux, java, ide, intellij

IntelliJ IDEA shows this message on every startup.

[image]

How can I correct this warning on IntelliJ IDEA?

Edit: I installed IntelliJ IDEA ultimate edition by yay on arch linux.

Comment: I think you might want to post this one on a different space since this one is targeted for Linux stuff. For instance, how did you install IntelliJ IDEA? The `.tar.gz` wouldn't have that problem. You basically need to use the bundled `JRE` from IntelliJ IDEA, that's all.

Comment: Thank you for commnet. I edited info to post. How can I switch to idea jre ?

Comment: It's located in `${IDE_HOME}/jbr/`. You would need to set an environment variable `IDEA_JDK` to that location — but I'm almost sure that's the default behavior, so you might want to consider the way you "installed" IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Arch Linux:

- Install [jdk-jetbrains](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jdk-jetbrains/) from AUR.
- put in ~/.bash_profile `export IDEA_JDK=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-jetbrains`

Comment: If you show me how to export the path to fish I will accept your answer

Comment: @JanČerný  haha...

add path temporarily...

`$ set -gx PATH $PATH <path>`


to set it permanently you have to write it in your config.fish which is usually at ~/.config/fish (if it exists, otherwise create it...)


`$touch ~/.config/fish/config.fish`
`$ echo "set -gx PATH \$PATH <path>" >> ~/.config/fish/config.fish`

Comment: I did change it, exported in path and installed from aur and still get the message. What am I missing?

Comment: Is this really required?

Comment: I added it to my `.zshrc` file and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, so I'll add to [EnigmaCurry](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/638229/412420)'s answer here:

If the variable `IDEA_JDK` doesn't work, launch action search and select "Choose Boot Java Runtime for the IDE" to switch to the downloaded Java. The only weird thing is that the font settings are changed after this.